# Driver not loaded mySql

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

I'm using Pycharm with Python3.9 and PyQt 5.15.2 and QSqlDatabase I followed the instructions on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql How to Build the QMYSQL Plugin on Windows. I used the mingw81_64 compiler. The file qsqlmysql.dll has been generated and I have copied it to PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers in my virtual environment. I also copied the file libmydql.dll to PyQt5/Qt5/bin in my virtual environment. If I execute database.drivers() I get the following ['QSQLITE', 'QMARIADB', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']. I got the following error "Driver not loaded" I also tried downloading the file qsqlmysql.dll from https://github.com/weldermarcosxd/pyqt5-mysql/blob/master/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlmysql.dll but I got the same error. I'm using this database https://remotemysql.com/ but I also tried with a local MySql Server and I got the same error. SQLlite works fine.

```
class Login(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_widgets()
    self.set_styles()
    self.connectSQLlite()

def connect(self):
    server = 'remotemysql.com'
    database_name = '****'
    user_name = '****'
    password = '****'

    self.database = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    self.database.setHostName(server)
    self.database.setDatabaseName(database_name)
    self.database.setUserName(user_name)
    self.database.setPassword(password)
    ok = self.database.open()
    if ok:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print(self.database.lastError().text())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile plugin with same compiler that your Qt binaries were compiled.

Comment: I am using Pycharm and installed PyQt version 5.15.2 with pip how can I know with which compiler where the Qt binaries compiled?

Comment: @bdf Usually libs for python are compiled with native compiler (msvc on windows), also you can verify it with [dependancy walker](http://dependencywalker.com/): if you open qt5network.dll in it, you'll see it depends on vcruntime140.dll, (msvc runtime) and does not depend on libstdc++-6.dll libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (mingw runtime), so it's very likely it's compiled with msvc 2019 or msvc 2016